# How can I update multiple documents in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I found the following script:

```
Device.find(function(err, devices) {
  devices.forEach(function(device) {
    device.cid = '';
    device.save();
  });
});
```

MongoDB has the "multi" flag for an update over multiple documents but I wasn't able to get this working with mongoose. Is this not yet supported or am I doing something wrong?

```
Device.update({}, {cid: ''}, false, true, function (err) {
  //...
});
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Currently I believe that `update()` in Mongoose has some problems, see: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#%21topic/mongoose-orm/G8i9S7E8Erg
and https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongoose-orm/K5pSHT4hJ_A/discussion.

However, check the docs for update: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html (its under Model). The definition is:

**Earlier Solution(Depreciated after mongoose 5+ version)**

```
Model.update = function (query, doc, options, callback) { ... }
```

You need to pass the options inside an object, so your code would be:

```
Model.update = function ({}, {cid: ''}, {multi: true}, function(err) { ... });
```

**New Solution**

```
Model.updateMany = function (query, doc, callback) { ... }

Model.updateMany = function ({}, {cid: ''}, function(err) { ... });
```

I believe that Mongoose wraps your cid in a $set, so this is not the same as running that same update in the mongo shell. If you ran that in the shell then all documents would be replaced by one with a single `cid: ''`.

Comment: this does exactly what i wanted ... to update all Devices' cids to ''. thx

Comment: why are you show us function definition? this is misleading to think you might suggest us to override custom functions, should you print it as so: `Device.updateMany({}, { cid: '' });` just as @Moh .S answered?

Answer (score 41):

Those answers are deprecated. This is the actual solution:

```
Device.updateMany({}, { cid: '' });
```

Answer (score 21):

You have to use the multi: true option

```
Device.update({},{cid: ''},{multi: true});
```

Answer (score 4):

as mentioned in the [mongoose documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) this is how we do this:

`db.collection.updateMany(condition, update, options, callback function)`

so this is an example based on the docs:

```
    // creating arguments
    let conditions = {};
    let update = {
        $set : {
      title : req.body.title,
      description : req.body.description,
      markdown : req.body.markdown
      }
    };
    let options = { multi: true, upsert: true };

    // update_many :)
    YourCollection.updateMany(

      conditions, update, options,(err, doc) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        if(!err) {
          res.redirect('/articles');
        }
        else {
          if(err.name == "ValidationError"){
            handleValidationError(err , req.body);
            res.redirect('/new-post');
          }else {
            res.redirect('/');
          }
        }
      });
```

this worked fine for me, I hope it helps :)

Comment: This is the only answer that actually worked and yet it only had 0 votes? For some reason it only works with the callback, which is strange

Comment: For the new guys like me, this answer was easier to read and use for a solution. Although, I didn't need the res.redirect portion of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
await Device.updateMany({_id: {$in: cid}},{ $set: {columnNameHere: "columnValueHere"}},{multi:true,upsert: true,new: true});
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but a great part of the quality level of the site comes from the fact that people go to great lengths to explain the **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Answer (score 0):

as @sina mentioned:

```
let conditions = {};
let options = { multi: true, upsert: true };

Device.updateMany(conditions , { cid: '' },options );
```

you can add a callback function after `options` but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way

```
try {
    const icMessages = await IcMessages.updateMany({
        room: req.params.room
    }, {
        "$set": {
            seen_status_2: "0"
        }
    }, {
        "multi": true
    });
    res.json(icMessages)

} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
    res.status(500).json({
        message: err.message
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Mongoose:
Link: [Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.updateMany())

Example:

```
exports.setHasInsurance = (patientId, hasInsurance) => {
  return Promise.resolve(
    EncounterPush.updateMany(
      { patientId: patientId },
      {
        hasInsurance: hasInsurance,
      }
    )
  );
};
```