# Update command in mongoose is removing old sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document in a collection, here address is a sub document

```
{
 name:'Belmont Race', 
 address:{city:'Brentwood', state:'TN', postal:'35704'}
}
```

Here is my UPDATE query in mongoose,

```
Let where={name:'Belmont Race'};
Let set={$set:{'address.state':'PN'}};
companies.updateMany(where,set, (err,res)=>{
if(err){console.log(err);}
// do something
})
```

Expected output is,

```
{name:'Belmont Race', address:{city:'Brentwood', state:'PN', postal:'35704'}}
```

But it removing old entire address sub document and giving the output like below

```
{name:'Belmont Race', address:{ state:'TN' }}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Working for me.Can you give more proof about this situation

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694507/how-can-i-update-multiple-documents-in-mongoose), you just need to change this line `Let set={$set:{'address.state':'PN'}};` to `Let set={'address.state':'PN'};` then your problem will be solved.