# Does mongoose have a findAndUpdate function?

Tags: reactjs, mongoose

I am aware that mongoose has findOneAndUpdate that can only filter one value.
How can I filter two values?

```
await ReceiptDetails.findAndUpdate(
    {patientIDnumber:patientIDnumber,
    appNum:appNum
    }, 
    {dateIssued:date, 
    addedItem: addedItemValue,
    paymentType:paymentType,
    totalAmount:totalAmount,
    officialReceiptNum:officialReceiptNum,
    addedProcedurePrice:addedProcedurePrice,
    amountPaid:amountPaid,
  }
  )
```

These are the only option that I have. [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update multiple documents in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694507/how-can-i-update-multiple-documents-in-mongoose)

Comment: I want to `filter` multiple values, not `update` the values

Comment: by using findbyOne, I can only filter `patientIDnumber:patientIDnumber` and I want to filter both `patientIDnumber:patientIDnumber` and `appNum:appNum`

Comment: than you can use only `find` function

Comment: I am using find function now thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use `updateMany()` for updating multiple records, api [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-updateMany) says response of this function has fields such as matchedCount, modifiedCount, upsertedId etc, see below:

```js
const res = await Person.updateMany({ name: /Stark$/ }, { isDeleted: true });
res.matchedCount; // Number of documents matched
res.modifiedCount; // Number of documents modified
res.acknowledged; // Boolean indicating everything went smoothly.
res.upsertedId; // null or an id containing a document that had to be upserted.
res.upsertedCount; // Number indicating how many documents had to be upserted. Will either be 0 or 1.
```

Comment: I want to `filter` multiple values, not `update` the values

Comment: by using `findbyOne`, I can only filter `patientIDnumber:patientIDnumber`  and I want to filter both `patientIDnumber:patientIDnumber` and `appNum:appNum`

Comment: in your question you have said findAndUpdate, which is confusing, if you want to query data, you should be using find api as suggested by @luís-mestre

Comment: I am using find function now thank you!